# gcloud login network connection failed issue

Tags: proxy, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I tried to connect gcloud with `gcloud init`. I got Network connection error.

I tried to fix with [Network connection problems in Google Cloud SDK while I have access to google or website like google app engine in my browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595789/network-connection-problems-in-google-cloud-sdk-while-i-have-access-to-google-or)

```
gcloud config set proxy/type socks5
gcloud config set proxy/address 127.0.0.1
gcloud config set proxy/port 1086
```

But it still does not work for me.

My log is:

```
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Settings from your current configuration [default] are:
core:
  disable_usage_reporting: 'False'
proxy:
  address: 127.0.0.1
  port: '1080'
  type: socks5

Pick configuration to use:
 [1] Re-initialize this configuration [default] with new settings 
 [2] Create a new configuration
 [3] Switch to and re-initialize existing configuration: [cindy]
Please enter your numeric choice:  1

Your current configuration has been set to: [default]

You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:
  gcloud init --skip-diagnostics

Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...done.                                                                                                                                        
ERROR: Reachability Check failed.
    Cannot reach https://www.google.com (error)
    Cannot reach https://accounts.google.com (error)
    Cannot reach https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects (error)
    Cannot reach https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform (error)
    Cannot reach https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json (error)
Network connection problems may be due to proxy or firewall settings.

Current effective Cloud SDK network proxy settings:
    type = socks5
    host = 127.0.0.1
    port = 1080
    username = None
    password = None

What would you like to do?
 [1] Change Cloud SDK network proxy properties
 [2] Clear all gcloud proxy properties
 [3] Exit
```

Comment: Do you have a proxy installed|running on localhost? If not, installing a proxy or VPN should be your first step. You need to get to a point where your machine can reach e.g. google.com.

Answer (score 2):

It is due to redirection from goolge account to localhost for acquiring token  Try to login using firefox

Answer (score 1):

For the people who still have this problem.

Try to use IPV4 first as IPV6 is still buggy for many systems.

For Linux, you can just uncomment or add the following line in /etc/gai.conf file:

precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100

For other systems, you can google the set-up

Answer (score 0):

Considering the error and mainly the following part of the error, it seems that you are facing issues with your proxy and firewall settings and configuration.

> Network connection problems may be due to proxy or firewall settings.

Due to this error, you need to configure your SDK to be used with proxy and firewall. I would recommend you to take a look at the documentation [Configuring Cloud SDK for use behind a proxy/firewall](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/proxy-settings), to get more information and steps on how to achieve it and avoid the error that you are facing.

Besides that, I could find the below two posts from the Community, of users that are facing similar cases that you are facing.

- [ERROR: Reachability Check failed. #51](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker/issues/51)
- [gcloud utility not working #25](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-runtime/issues/25)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much. I already set my config as 127.0.0.1/8080/sock5, but I still could not `gcloud init`. And I also tried `gcloud init --dns 8.8.8.8` the result will be (gcloud.init) unrecognized arguments: --dns

Comment: Hi @cindywmiao checking this page [here](http://www.programmersought.com/article/2225467784/;jsessionid=6B89D65C226220EA4B3CEEBB5B779DCD), it seems that your `port = 1080` needs to be configured like ```port = `1080` ```. Could you please give it a try? Besides that, reading further, it seems that there are some possibilities for the error that you are facing. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45927259/google-cloud-python-sdk-installation-error-ssl-certification-error) on the Community has some additional solutions, that I would recommend you to take a look at it.